# Using PHP variables in jQuery plugin initialization?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a jQuery image gallery plugin that I'm using extensively throughout a site for which I'm building PHP templates. In the properties for the plugin initialization, most of the values will remain the same throughout the site, aside from a few exceptions. In these instances, I'm wondering if it's ok for me to pass in a value for the property via PHP; e.g. if there is a property called "thumbnailsVisible" in certain cases I will want this set to true, and in others, false. Thus, is there anything wrong with assigning a value to a corresponding variable and including the following in the jQuery initialization within the template:

```
thumbnailsVisible : <?php echo $thumbnailsVisible; ?>
```

I realize I could also just externalize the initialization in a js file and create different versions as needed, but this would be much simpler provided there isn't anything wrong with this approach...

Also, if there's a completely different approach that would be optimal, I'd appreciate any sort of assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can do this.

PHP is processed on the server side and only sent to client when it's processed.

You could write a php script to return the JavaScript and pass in an argument.

Eg.

```
<?php
$thumbnailVisible = isset($_GET['showthumb']) ? $_GET['showthumb'] : 'false';
?>
$.func({
    thumbnailsVisible: <?php echo $thumbnailVisible; ?>
});
```

If it doesn't work correctly, try specify the `content-type` using `header()`.

```
header('Content-type: application/javascript');
```

Place this at the top of the PHP script.

Comment: Thanks, Jose; that's very helpful. Since the vast majority of cases will indeed have thumbnails in the slider, and thus have the property set to "true", is there a way I can have the php default to true *if* no variable is set?

Comment: Yes. With this `$thumbnailVisible = isset($_GET['showthumb']) ? $_GET['showthumb'] : 'true';`

Comment: Ah ok cool-- got it. Thanks much. Time to spend some time with the PHP manual... :)

Comment: just as an update here-- I decided to go with what seems to be a more elegant solution for setting a default value, i.e. `isset($thumbnailVisible) or $thumbnailVisible = 'true';`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do that , actually i come across cases like that very often and i usually do the same .
You can check the code [here](https://github.com/gencms/sample-gencms/blob/master/app/modules/news_category/controllers/news_category.php#L40) :
(Although that is based on codeIgniter)